# Incorrect format when converting FileVersion ToDouble

Tags: c#, double

I am making a small program that downloads files from internet, depending on the file version of another file.

Here is some of the code (where I am getting an error):

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load("http://raiderz.daregamer.com/updates/app_version.xml");
XmlNodeList xNodeVer = xdoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("Version");
FileVersionInfo fileVer = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "FileCheckVer.exe");
double ver_app = Convert.ToDouble(fileVer.FileVersion.ToString());
double ver_xml = Convert.ToDouble(xNodeVer);
```

The error says, "Input string was not in a correct format." and points to the following line.

```
double ver_app = Convert.ToDouble(fileVer.FileVersion.ToString());
```

Does anyone know what the correct format is?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answers!
Now I have another problem... I added the information to the first post.

Comment: Rolled back.  Don't change your question, ask another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A FileVersion is in the Format d.d.d.d (2.0.0.0), where a double is just a floating point number (d.d).

All the information you need is in the [FileVersionInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) instance you already created (check the properties).

**/EDIT**

Answer to Q2. You need to use SelectSingleNode() to return an XmlNode, then you look at the .Value property of that.

Answer (score 2):

It's a four part number, e.g. 1.2.3.4. What `double` value did you expect to get out of that?

If you want to get at each of the bits of it, then rather than converting it to a string and then trying to parse it, just use [`FileVersionInfo` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyxea3y3.aspx) such as `FileMajorPart` etc.